# How to remove automounting without system access on CentOS

Tags: linux, hard-drive, centos, mount

I have a Nethserver server (based on CentOS 7) and recently one of the disks failed. There was nothing important on the disk so I just removed it.

But the disk was set to automatically mount to `/mnt/disk1` and since then the system doesn't want to boot anymore.

I checked the logs and confirmed that it is trying to mount the disk and I believe this is the reason it doesn't want to boot anymore.

```
[* ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-c418cb0c\x2d...944\x2d8639\x2d90b84dc0dab2.device (1min 29s / 1min 30s[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\ x2duuid-c418cb0c\x2d03ba\x2d4944\x2d8639\x2d90b84dc0dab2.device.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /mnt/disk1.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Mark the need to relabel after reboot.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Migrate local SELinux policy changes from the old store structure to the new structure.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Relabel all filesystems, if necessary.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Collectd statistics daemon.
```

Is there any way I can disable automount just by modifying files on the system, as I can't boot it to do this from the command-line?

I have access to the disk from my computer, I can edit the files but I dont know how to disable it.

Comment: You should be able to just edit `/etc/fstab` and comment out the line pertaining to that disk if you still can get a shell in e.g. rescue mode.

Do you have console access? Can you get to the grub menu?

Comment: @tink - The file only contains the mount options for the main disk (boot, efi and swap partition).